# Call Range.Find method with MatchCase parameter

Tags: excel, powershell, parameter-passing

I have some Powershell code that is trying to find a particular string in a range of an Excel sheet. It uses the `Find` method from the excel libraries. Here is the code:

```
$default = [Type]::Missing
$objRange.find($Search,$default,$default,$xlLookAt::xlPart,$xlSearchOrder::xlByRows,$xlSearchDirection::xlNext, $true ,$default,$default)
```

What does not work is the `$true` value I am passing to specify `MatchCase` mode. I have tried `True`, `$true`, `-1`, `"true"`, etc. `True` works on ISE command line, but the Powershell ISE editor does not like it.

What do I pass for `MatchCase` parameter for True, or for False?

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is the documentation of the `Range.Find` method.

Comment: `$true` should work. How *exactly* does it "not work" for you?

Comment: Strange.  Today $true works.  I have no clue what could have changed in my environment that would have affected this. Thanks for the feedback.